# React-native problems "unable to resolve module"!

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

[image: 这个是报错信息( this is err)]

[image: 这是我的项目目录(this is project)]

## Header 1

1.当我引入自己写的组件的时候,就报这个错误,
  (when i import module which i create,the err appear),
   i have already tried restart the project

Comment: Ask a question in the English language only.

Comment: OK my english not very well

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine.You can change the ext. of your home file.Change your extension from Home.jsx to Home.js.and rebuild the module.Hope it will work.

Comment: thanks very much i find the reason. i didn t edit  last line for export Home.

Comment: but do you know  how to import antd-mobile component ,when i import component of antd-mobile,react-native also appear the err, unabled resolve module antd-mobile,, i install antd-mobile and react-dom, why install react-dom?